# sql server time from UTC to GMT

Tags: sql, sql-server

I live in England and for some odd reason our CRM system is set to UTC out of the box and nothing can be changed about that. It differs by an hour, just wondering if there is an efficient way to get the time to be correct? It varies by an hour, but because the times change twice a year just wondering how this can be tackled?

Comment: GMT and UTC are interchangable all through the year. Non of them has Daylight saving time.

Comment: You can change the times zone setting of the server where the instance is installed... or change the data and time of the server it self.

Comment: Im afraid its not an option as my manager has mentioned. You mean on the SQL server box in which we have the snapshot of CRM?

Comment: In England, we move from GMT to BST for daylight savings. GMT remains GMT and is UTC+0.